# User Control form performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel

I intend using a feedback form on all pages of a site by adding a User Control with an UpdatePanel to my master page.  Is this likely to have much of an adverse effect on server load / page load time?

Comment: If you're using `UpdatePanel`s anyway, why are you reloading the complete page? Otherwise i don't understand why it should have a performance impact. You can set the `UpdatePanel`'s `UpdateMode` to `Conditional` and update the content only if needed manually from codebehind, for example from a method in your masterpage.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. I'm wondering if the addition of the User control itself has any specific impact on the initial page load time as I'm adding it to the master page.

Comment: Not if it you encapsulate all time consuming logic into separate methods that are called lazily, so just if they are needed. Many people databind `UserControls` in `Page_Load`(of the UC) which is the wrong place. Do that from a separate method that is called from it's controller(the `MasterPage`) and only if it's really needed (f.e. the user clicked a button "Refresh").